# swagger API documentation with my own yaml file

Tags: api, swagger

I have my API documented with Swagger. For developer convenience I would like to provide the swagger GUI on my website as well. However, my provider has not installed the php yaml extension. It implies that I can't use the GUI on my own website.

So, I would like to use a third party GUI. I know that I can use https://petstore.swagger.io/ and enter the link to my yaml file in the text box. This is also not really user friendly. I prefer to open the GUI and specify the yaml when calling the url. For the user the GUI opens with my API definition.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Swagger UI is a static web page (HTML + JS + CSS). You don't need the PHP YAML extension to host it, just upload the dist assets + your OpenAPI file (JSON or YAML) to a folder on your server.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you cannot host Swagger UI youself, here are some alternatives you can try:

- Use [**SwaggerHub**](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/) to host your API definition and docs.
  *Disclosure: I work for the company that makes SwaggerHub.*
- Use **GitLab** to host your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file. GitLab [uses Swagger UI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/#openapi-viewer) to render OpenAPI files. Example:
  https://gitlab.com/gofus/gofus-api/blob/dev/swagger.yaml
- Use https://petstore.swagger.io with the `url` query parameter to automatically load your API definition:

  ```
  https://petstore.swagger.io?url=https://yoursite.com/api.yaml
  ```

  For this to work, the server where your OpenAPI file is hosted must use HTTPS and [support CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server.html).